# Regex timing out

Tags: regex, timeout, infinite-loop

I'm trying to match something like

```
foo: anything after the colon can be matched with (.*)+
foo.bar1.BAZ: balh5317{}({}(
```

This is the regex I'm using:

```
/^((?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z_]+)(?:[0-9]+)?)+[\.]?)+)(?:\s)?(?:\:)(?:\s)?((?:.*)+)$/
```

Excuse the non-matching groups and extra parens, this is being compiled from a builder class

This works on the examples. The problem arises when I try to put in a string like this:

```
foo.bar.baz.beef.stew.ect.and.forward
```

I need to be able to check strings like this, but the regex engine times out or runs infinity (as far as I can tell) after a certain amount of `foo.`s every time.

I'm sure this is a logical problem I could figure out, but unfortunately I've far from mastered regex and I hoped a more experienced user could shed some light on how I can make this more efficient.

Also, here is a more detailed description of what I need to match:

```
Property Name: can contain A-z, numbers, and underscores but can't start with a number

<Property Name>.<Property Name>.<Prop...:<Anything after the colon>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: When I tried to write it from scratch I came up with `\b((?:[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\.?)*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*):(.+)` which works but is almost the same as your RegEx… there’s no infinite loop happening with this one on http://regex101.com. But I could confirm a timeout for your RegEx!

Comment: Okay, so apparently it works if those `^` and `$` marks are removed and the `g` flag was set instead.

Comment: I think this is relevant: [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your regex:

```
^((?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z_]+)(?:[0-9]+)?)+[\.]?)+)(?:\s)?(?:\:)(?:\s)?((?:.*)+)$


 ^                                  # Anchors to the beginning to the string.
 (                                  # Opens CG1
     (?:                            # Opens NCG
         (?:                        # Opens NCG
             (?:                    # Opens NCG
                 [A-Za-z_]+         # Character class (any of the characters within)
             )                      # Closes NCG
             (?:                    # Opens NCG
                 [0-9]+             # Character class (any of the characters within)
             )?                     # Closes NCG
         )+                         # Closes NCG
         [\.]?                      # Character class (any of the characters within)
     )+                             # Closes NCG
 )                                  # Closes CG1
 (?:                                # Opens NCG
     \s                             # Token: \s (white space)
 )?                                 # Closes NCG
 (?:                                # Opens NCG
     \:                             # Literal :
 )                                  # Closes NCG
 (?:                                # Opens NCG
     \s                             # Token: \s (white space)
 )?                                 # Closes NCG
 (                                  # Opens CG2
     (?:                            # Opens NCG
         .*                         # . denotes any single character, except for newline
     )+                             # Closes NCG
 )                                  # Closes CG2
 $                                  # Anchors to the end to the string.
```

I converted `[0-9]` to `\d`, simply for easier readability (both match the same thing). I also removed a lot of non-capturing groups because they weren't really being used.

```
^((?:(?:[A-Za-z_]+\d*)+\.?)+)\s?\:\s?((?:.*)+)$
```

I also merged the `\s` and .* into `[\s\S]*`, but seeing that it was followed by a `+` sign, i removed the group and just made `[\s\S]`.

```
^((?:(?:[A-Za-z_]+\d*)+\.?)+)\s?\:([\s\S]+)$
                      ^
```

Now I'm not sure what the `+` above the carat is supposed to do. We can remove it, and thusly the non-capturing group surrounding it.

```
^((?:[A-Za-z_]+\d*\.?)+)\s?\:([\s\S]+)$
```

Explanation:

```
 ^                          # Anchors to the beginning to the string.
 (                          # Opens CG1
     (?:                    # Opens NCG
         [A-Za-z_]+         # Character class (any of the characters within)
         \d*                # Token: \d (digit)
         \.?                # Literal .
     )+                     # Closes NCG
 )                          # Closes CG1
 \s?                        # Token: \s (white space)
 \:                         # Literal :
 (                          # Opens CG2
     [\s\S]+                # Character class (any of the characters within)
 )                          # Closes CG2
 $                          # Anchors to the end to the string.
```

Now, you might want to change the `[\s\S]+` back to `.*` if you're dealing with multiple lines. There are a few different options regarding that but it kind of matters what language you're using.

Honestly, I did this in steps but the largest problem was `(?:.*)+` This is telling the engine to `match 0 or more characters 1 or more times` [catastrophic backtracking (as xufox linked to in comments)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

**The resulting regex, and your original too, permits variables that end in `.` I'd use something more like this, which your regex really wasn't that far from.**

This will match names like foo.ba5r, if that's acceptable, your prior regex wouldn't.

```
^([A-Za-z_]\w*(?:\.[A-Za-z_]+\w*)*)\s?\:([\s\S]+)$
```

Explanation:

```
 ^                          # Anchors to the beginning to the string.
 (                          # Opens CG1
     [A-Za-z_]              # Character class (any of the characters within)
     \w*                    # Token: \w (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
     (?:                    # Opens NCG
         \.                 # Literal .
         [A-Za-z_]          # Character class (any of the characters within)
         \w*                # Token: \w (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
     )*                     # Closes NCG
 )                          # Closes CG1
 \s?                        # Token: \s (white space)
 \:                         # Literal :
 (                          # Opens CG2
     [\s\S]+                # Character class (any of the characters within)
 )                          # Closes CG2
 $                          # Anchors to the end to the string.
```

Comment: With the `\.` being in a group with the `+` quantifier this doesn’t match `foo: bar`.

Comment: @Xufox Indeed, typo (and I wouldn't have caught it, I was sure I used an asterisk. Thanks. will fix) (edit: fixed)

Comment: What about `foo3_test: bar`? Won’t match either, unfortunately…

Comment: Thought about that one as you were commenting, and fixed. I was kind of trying to work with his pattern, but I agree that numbers in the string, as long as not at the start, is probably more like the intended goal. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: Okay, neither can I reproduce a case of catastrophic backtracking nor can I find any matching mistakes; nice job! But you’ve written that the main issue was `(.+)*` although the _actual_ issue seems to be the `.` which you replaced by a `[\s\S]`. When I do the same replacement in my RegEx from the comments then my RegEx works as well. When I replace `[\s\S]` back to a `.` in your RegEx it times out again (e. g. “foooooo.baaaaaar: x\ny”). So I guess you’ll have to match anything after `:` in a multiline way otherwise it becomes problematic…

Comment: @Xufox Tossing my regex at simple data in regexr, both work fine for me, although OP's original regex immediately threw a timeout at me. However, I must bid you adieu. It's late and I can no longer tell my backslashes from my forward slashes :)